# Can I save a web page to my SD card with the stock android browser?

Tags: sd-card

Can I save a web page to my SD card with the stock android browser?  I'm using an HTC Droid Eris, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

There is an application called [Save Webpage](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/save-webpage_hymo.html) which will let you do it, I don't know of any  other way to do it in the stock browser.

Answer (score 1):

[WebMemo](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/webmemo_jsbh.html) (Updated name [Save as Web Archive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.fuukiemonster.webmemo)) does a similar thing, but seems a bit more at hand as it uses the *Share Page* menu, instead of having you manually input the url - as with the fore-mentioned *Save Webpage*

Google play [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.fuukiemonster.webmemo)